# Show line number where Rails test fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing

For some reason the line number where unit test is failing is not show. New in Rails 3? I'm not sure. This makes it very difficult to know where the test is failing. The only way to know which line is causes the error is to put debug statements everwhere in your test code.

Example of the output is below. The example shows a lot of useful information. For example the error message: wrong number of arguments (o for 2). Unfortunately it doesn't show the line number of the unit test code line. Is it possibly to get the line number?

```
ActionController::TestCase
ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
ActiveRecord::TestCase
ActiveSupport::TestCase
DefineIssueTest
     test_Get_issues                                                     ERROR
        wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)
        STDERR:
        Exception `ArgumentError' at c:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesu
pport-3.1.4/lib/active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb:35:in `block in run
'
        c:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.4/lib/active_suppor
t/callbacks.rb:408:in `_run_setup_callbacks'
        c:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.4/lib/active_suppor
t/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
        c:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.4/lib/active_suppor
t/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb:34:in `run'
Test::Unit::TestCase
==============================================================================
  pass: 0,  fail: 0,  error: 1
  total: 1 tests with 20 assertions in 0.935994 seconds
==============================================================================
Errors running test:single!
```

Comment: Currently I'm adding trace statements to determine the last succesfully executed test code line. I must doing something wrong? Rails must have a better way to do this?

Comment: The error seems to stem from the "setup_and_teardown" method in active_support/testing. Do you have any setup-code for your test, that might be failing?

Answer (score 0):

I had that issue recently; it turns out that I had written a test that was failing in the test suite itself.  (Minimum password length: 8 characters.  Then I set an example with 6 characters.) Took me forever to figure out the problem because the error messages were non-sensical.